# Medians and Perpendicular bisectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

There was something I never quite understood about medians and perpendicular bisectors in a triangle, or to be more specific, an isosceles triangle; Aren't they the same in this kind of triangle?  If not all are the same, than, at least the median to the base of the triangle is also a perpendicular bisector, due to the qualities of median to the base in an isosceles triangle?

Comment: Your last question is correct. The median to and perpendicular bisector of the base are the same. The median to and perpendicular bisector of the congruent sides are not the same.

Comment: indeed, because they do not serve as angle bisectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.[image: this]

AD serves as the median (from A to BC) as well as the perpendicular bisector (of BC).

This is not necessarily true for the other two sides unless the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: It sums it up pretty well, thanks.